# Align table columns by equal sign

Tags: tables, dcolumn

So I know I can align columns by a comma with the `dcolumn` package like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{d{2} d{2}}
    \toprule
    $T\ $ [\si{\kelvin}] & $B\ $ [\si{\centi\meter\cubed\per\mole}] \\
    \midrule
    100 & -187,0 \\
    273 & -21,7 \\
    300 & -15,0 \\
    373 & -4,2 \\
    412 & 0,0 \\
    600 & 11,9 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Not the most minimal example, but it'll do. Now, I'd like to align columns by an equal sign instead of a comma. The problem seems to be related to the fact that the equal sign (`=`) is inside some inline math like `$$`.

A minimal example of this is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{d{2} d{2}}
    $a = 1$ & $1 = 3$ \\
    $\int = 3$ & $ 7 = \sum 3$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

A copy of the table I'm making can be found on pastebin [Here](http://pastebin.com/eKF8iMyV) (don't mind the warnings about margins & stuff) and looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution without `dcolumn`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{4}{
    >{$}r<{$}
    @{}>{${}={}$}c@{}
    >{$}l<{$}
  }
}
  \toprule
  Process &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Indre energi $\Delta U$} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Arbejde $w$} &
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Betingelser} \\
  \midrule
  Isokor &
    \Delta U && n \cdot C_{V,m} \cdot \Delta T &
    w && 0 &
    \frac{p}{T} && \mbox{konst,} &
    \Delta V && 0 \\
  Isobar &
    \Delta U && n \cdot C_{V,m} \cdot \Delta T &
    w && -n \cdot R \cdot \Delta T &
    \frac{V}{T} && \mbox{konst,} &
    \Delta p && 0 \\
  Isoterm &
    \Delta U && 0 &
    w && -n \cdot R \cdot T \cdot \ln\frac{V_f}{V_i} &
    p \cdot V && \mbox{konst,} &
    \Delta T && 0 \\
  Adiabat &
    \Delta U && w &
    w && n \cdot C_{V,m} \cdot \delta T &
    p \cdot V^\gamma && \mbox{konst,} &
    \gamma && \frac{C_{p,m}}{C_{V,m}} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Nice, a bit more complicated than first expected... I believe there was another answer involving ``dcolumn`` but it disapeared somehow. One thing; how can I get a the no-go vertical line between column 1 & 2?

Comment: @Argo Usually good tables do not have vertical lines. Add `|` (bar) after the first column specification `l` (lowercase L), then you get a line similar to the line in the question's image.

Comment: I know, but in my opinion, it's ok in this situation. Thanks again.

Comment: @Argo The other answer was deleted by its owner. The alignment at the equals sign is easier with package `dcolumn`. But the difficult part is the centering without additional space at the left or right, and it is even more difficult, when arbitrary formulas are used.